# how java stored the upcasted reference type variable in their memory

Tags: java, jvm

```
        Car truck = new Truck(Car.Brand.BMW, Car.Color.BLUE, 2022, 2000);
        System.out.println(truck);
        // Truck@7dc36524

        Truck sample = (Truck)truck;
        System.out.println(sample);
        // Truck@7dc36524
```

**cause as far as I know, when we create the instance, the data is stored in heap area and the reference and type information are stored in `stack` area.**
so I expected that the `System.out.println(truck)` will print `Car@7dc36524` but it wasn't

so now it makes me wonder
where is the type information for the reference type variable stored?

Comment: the instance is not changed in any way. The called method - `toString` here - is just the method of the given instance.

Comment: Type information is stored on the instance. Casting has no effect on it.